# How to catch a pull request event to a specific branch in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to catch an event of opening a pr into development branch from branch x.
I tried this, but am getting false:

`${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/development'}}`

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include your relevant workflow in your question along with debugging details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

`github.event.pull_request.base.ref == 'development'`

[Source](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27154)